# What is the best way to copy sqlite file when its in use within an iOS app

Tags: ios, cocoa, sqlite, xcode4

I have an iOS app which use sqlite as the db and I want to copy a sqlite file when its in use. What is the best way to do this. Right now i am just copying the file using copyItemAtPath in NSFileManager . Is this the best way ?. Will this damage the original db file ?. Note that db is heavily use at the time it need to be coped.

Comment: See http://sqlite.org/c3ref/backup_finish.html

Comment: I think I'd want to have the DB file locked before copying.

Comment: how can i do it within a app

Comment: @Panchaz See the docs I referenced. In your app you make use of those backup functions. You can copy the live database as it's being used.